# Mathematica: is it possible to make an automatic init.m file for simple packages

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Most of my personal packages are just a single m-file, say `Foo.m`, but they usually end up as `Foo/Foo.m` so that I can store related tests and notes in the `Foo` directory as well. To allow the packages to be loaded with just `` <<Foo` ``, I include `Foo/init.m` as follows:

```
With[{packagename="Foo"},
  Get@FileNameJoin@{ 
    DirectoryName@FindFile[packagename<>"`"],
    packagename<>".m"}]
```

This works fine as long as I remember to update `packagename` when I copy `init.m` to new packages, but I was wondering if there is a way of making a completely reusable `init.m` for this simple case?

Just for completeness, I don't want to rename the implementation `implementation.m`.

Comment: So you want something the can be self-aware of its loading directory. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure to understand your question but here is a guess anyway ...

Did you try something like

```
packagename = StringDrop[DirectoryName[$Input], -1]
```

in your first line?

**Edit: for future reference**

After Janus test, it became that the correct expression is:

```
packagename=StringDrop[$Input,-2]
```

Comment: Spot on! I had been browsing around for something similar to 'NotebookFilename', but didn't manage to find it. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that a) $Input is not set to a full path and b) it seems to be the path supplied to `Get`, i.e. `$Input==Foo.m` when reading `Foo/init.m`. So it needs to be `packagename=StringDrop[$Input,-2]`.

Comment: @Janus Thanks! Glad it worked! I've edited my answer with the correct expression.